# Error :No Value gven for more required parameters in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2003

I have getting error while update the data to Access db from VB.NET. Which is shown `"No value given for more required parameters"`. Here i have given the code what i have tried.....

```
con.open()
dim a
dim cd as new oledb.oledbcommand
a="update inward set Quantity=" & textbox3.text & "Where tool_name=" & listbopx1.selectedItemm & ""
cd=new oledb.oledbcommand(a,con)
cd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.close
```

Please help me to fix this, I need to know why it has happened.

Comment: I have getting cleared by myself. Thanks to give me a chance to use this website. In future if i got any problem i will ask.. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you have all the columns with the same name you are using as in the query..!!

Comment: You can post the solution as an answer to your own question (I assume it's because you were missing a space between `textbox3.text`'s value and the word `where`, and possibly the quoting issue Martin suggested). It will help you or others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think a problem with quotes

```
a="update inward set Quantity=" & textbox3.text & "Where tool_name=" & listbopx1.selectedItemm & ""
```

should it not be

```
a="update inward set Quantity=" & textbox3.text & " Where tool_name='" & listbopx1.selectedItemm & "'"
```

and watch out for quotes in the string.

So my advice: use parameterized queries,

I added a link to see how to write parameters. Look at :
[Running a Query, getting a value, then update record in ASP.net (VB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687397/running-a-query-getting-a-value-then-update-record-in-asp-net-vb/6704191#6704191)

Comment: When you post code, you can mark it as such by indenting by 4 spaces, or highlighting it and pressing the `{}` code button. It gives syntax highlighting.

Comment: at work I have an old XP and a browser, that does not react on half of the buttons(error visualizing...). I'm doing my best with what I have and I thank you for the effort, Damien