# Running a PL SQL Select Query From ASP.NET page and Displaying Result in Data Table

Tags: asp.net, plsql, c#-3.0

I want to run a select PL/SQL query from my asp.net web page, say by creating a Button and on click it will execute a select statement and will display the result in a Data table.

I do not want to create a stored procedure and do this as this is not allowed.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

@Mukesh you can refer following links

[Running a Query, getting a value, then update record in ASP.net (VB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687397/running-a-query-getting-a-value-then-update-record-in-asp-net-vb)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx

Comment: Thanks Robby checking this :)